# How do I remove or rename a Bluemix organization after a name change?

Tags: ibm-cloud, organization

I try to remove my organization executing this command:

1) Change the original organization name from miguel@thingtrack.com to Miguel correctly from the Dashboard.

1) Login in my bluemix account correctly from CLI like this:

bluemix login

2) Try to remove my unique organization called Miguel:

```
bluemix iam org-delete Miguel
```

The error result is:

```
Suprimiendo la organización Miguel como miguel@thingtrack.com...
FAILED
Error response from server. StatusCode: 500; description: multiple documents found containing guid 7f1f9939-b0bc-4e61-85b9-d7e3744b6c77: [{"_id":"org.Miguel","_rev":"3-9b1bba6c8f8c618ba424c728e55ee247","customer":"ibm","deployment":"yp","name":"Miguel","type":"org","value":{"ibm:yp:eu-gb":{"guid":"6b7219e6-5992-4d43-ac52-083bf0ce8d50","owner":true},"ibm:yp:us-south":{"guid":"7f1f9939-b0bc-4e61-85b9-d7e3744b6c77"}},"created_at":"2016-05-23T13:49:36.660Z","updated_at":"2016-09-09T17:50:02.846Z","migrated":true},{"_id":"org.miguel@thingtrack.com","_rev":"2-cf26e55555fe9730b4a9a9a4525f4bf3","customer":"ibm","deployment":"yp","name":"miguel@thingtrack.com","type":"org","value":{"ibm:yp:us-south":{"guid":"7f1f9939-b0bc-4e61-85b9-d7e3744b6c77","owner":true}},"created_at":"2015-08-28T09:49:49.221Z","updated_at":"2016-08-13T18:06:03.994Z","migrated":true}]
```

Also I noticed that if I try to rename again the organization to other name I obtain the same error.

So in my opinion if you change the organization name one time, you will never remove it or change the name never more.

Is it a bug of bluemix??

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix does not allow users to delete organizations. Per documentation you have to contact Bluemix Support team to delete the organization on your behalf.

From Bluemix documentation:

> You must contact Bluemix Support to delete an organization. When you
>   request for the support team to delete an organization, all the
>   spaces, applications, and services within the organization are
>   deleted.

You can find more details here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/orgs_spaces.html#orginfo

Comment: Sorry but this is not true, because I removed a organization from bluemix CLI, from other account, like this:

bluemix iam org-delete ORG_NAME 
[link](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/index.html#bluemix_iam_org_delete)

In that case the organization name was not renamed, so I did'n have any problem, but in the other case the organization name was renamed, so this is the only difference between the two cases that I check.

Comment: I am not sure how you were able to delete an organization in public Bluemix as this is not allowed. You can only delete organization in Dedicated or Local Bluemix environments.

Comment: Logically my question is for Bluemix Public and I used the Bluemix CLI command: bluemix iam org-delete ORG_NAME to remove this organization so it's possible and I think is right not depend of anybody to remove an old organization. The problem is with this renamed organization that give me the previous error 500.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Miguel Salinas is correct. You can now rename or delete orgs from the Bluemix CLI using commands such as:

```
bluemix iam org-rename <old_org_name> <new_org_name>
bluemix iam org-delete <org_name>
```

Here's the reference to the bluemix commands:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/index.html

The documentation snippet mentioned above by Alex is outdated and need to be revised. I'll send them this feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party, but I hope this helps the future users.
You can rename org using the bluemix cli as @marcel Ribas stated above.

**bluemix iam org-rename old_org_name new_org_name**

**bluemix iam org-delete org_name**

Alternatively you can go into your bluemix account and you have and option to change org name under the manange organizations tab. Just click on edit button next to org name and make the changes

Note- You need to have manager level access to the org you are trying to rename. You can check this on your bluemix account under the manage organizations tab